# Most efficient way to dump entire mysql result set into an array?

Tags: php, mysql, set

I am trying to put the entire results set into an array as follows:

```
while($myres[]=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

This works ok but if I have 5 rows returns in my results the array has 6 index the last being null. So it seems that my array is always one index too big.

I could use num_rows to loop the results but this requires me setting up my own counter and incrementing it, I like the shorthand efficiency of my line above but how to stop it populating the last index with a null set.

This is an alternative to me using `fetch_all` which I discovered requires a special driver which not all php servers have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use multiple lines

```
$myres = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $myres[] = $row;
```

However, if you *have* to have it without the extra array assignment line

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) && $myres[] = $row) {
```

but that is more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
while($myres[]=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

does the following:

1. execute `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`
2. assign the result of this expression to `$myres[]`, thereby appending an entry to the `$myres` array
3. pass the result of `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` as a condition to the `while` statement and determine whether the loop should be exited.

Notice that appending an entry to the `$myres` array happens *before* determining if the `while` loop should be exited. This is where your extra row comes from.

You will not lose *any* efficiency by doing it the classical way:

```
while ($record = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $myres[] = $record; 
}
```